# Quickest way to find 5 largest values in an array of structs

Tags: c

I have an array of `structs` called `struct Test testArray[25]`.

The `Test struct` contains a member called `int size`.

What is the fastest way to get another array of `Test structs` that contain all from the original excluding the 5 largest, based on the member `size`? WITHOUT modifying the original array.

NOTE: Amount of items in the array can be much larger, was just using this for testing and the values could be dynamic. Just wanted a slower subset for testing.

---

I was thinking of making a copy of the original `testArray` and then sorting that array. Then return an array of `Test structs` that did not contain the top 5 or bottom 5 (depending on asc or desc).

OR

Iterating through the `testArray` looking for the largest 5 and then making a copy of the original array excluding the largest 5. This way seems like it would iterate through the array too many times comparing to the array of 5 largest that had been found.

---

Follow up question:

Here is what i am doing now, let me know what you think?

Considering the number of largest elements i am interested in is going to remain the same, i am iterating through the array and getting the largest element and swapping it to the front of the array. Then i skip the first element and look for the largest after that and swap it into the second index... so on so forth. Until i have the first 5 largest. Then i stop sorting and just copy the sixth index to the end into a new array.

This way, no matter what, i only iterate through the array 5 times. And i do not have to sort the whole thing.

Comment: Is *fast* really a consideration if you're iterating over 25 items?

Comment: The amount of items is much larger, i was just using 25 as a base line for testing. And the amount could be dynamic, but i was just starting small.

Comment: Sorting is O(n log n) (quicksort). Iteration is O(n). Draw your own conclusions.

Comment: Ah ;) Well, that's slightly better.

Comment: I agree with @vanza –– why do you believe that you would need to iterate over the array more than twice?

Comment: Added a follow up question.

Comment: Adding follow up questions confuses everybody... still, you only need two iterations. First one finds the threshold above which there are only n elements. Second one copies everything but those n elements.

Comment: Yeah and asking a second question that is too similar makes moderators cranky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Partial Sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_sorting) with a linear time [selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) will do this in O(n) time, where sorting would be O(nlogn).

To quote the [Partial Sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_sorting) page:

*The linear-time selection algorithm described above can be used to find the k smallest or the k largest elements in worst-case linear time O(n). To find the k smallest elements, find the kth smallest element using the linear-time median-of-medians selection algorithm. After that, partition the array with the kth smallest element as pivot. The k smallest elements will be the first k elements.*

You can find the k largest items in O(n), although making a copy of the array or an array of pointers to each element (smarter) will cost you some time as well, but you have to do that regardless.

If you'd like me to give a complete explanation of the algorithm involved, just comment.

*Update:*
Regarding your follow up question, which basically suggests iterating over the list five times... that will work. But it iterates over the list more times than you need to. Finding the k largest elements in one pass (using an O(n) selection algorithm) is much better than that. That way you iterate once to make your new array, and once more to do the selection (if you use median-of-medians, you will not need to iterate a third time to remove the five largest items as you can just split the working array into two parts based on where the 5th largest item is), rather than iterating once to make your new array and then an additional five times.

Comment: my 950 pages Book Algorithms, (Sedgewick) did not have that sorting algo inside.

Comment: Wow. Here's a more specific wiki link: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Linear_general_selection_algorithm_-_Median_of_Medians_algorithm  And some related lecture slides: http://c3p0demo.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/scalaDemo/script/Order_statistics.ppt

Comment: The interesting thing that I would have needed that for a percentile calculation, however standard sorting even with hundreds thousands is fast enough, but when it comes to hundred millions elemnts , then i will think again at partial sorting.

Comment: O(n) worst cast is very very nice. Sorting a few hundred thousand items on a modern processor is still going to be pretty quick though.

Comment: I don't understand why you guys are so fixated in sorting things. His problem description does not require sorting anywhere. It can be solved by iterating over the original array twice (first to find the threshold, second to copy 5 elements into the target array).

Comment: Did you look at what a selection algorithm is?

Comment: Yes, still all the comments are talking about sorting, when all he needs is selection.

Comment: The comments are talking about sorting because AlexWein had never heard of partial sorting (which selection then partitioning out the k largest elements counts as for obvious reasons) and felt the need to point out that nlogn is still pretty quick for relatively small values of n. Stating the obvious, perhaps, but hardly worth complaining about.

Comment: indeed iterating twice is simpler, the reason why i thought about sorting, is that i thought for a practical application where e.g you  use that for percentile calculation, and there you need the median, 90%, 95, 99, 99,5 99,9% percentiles. Then simply iterating is not enough.

Comment: Added a follow up question.

Comment: Updated. Please don't find the 5 largest items by iterating 5 times... not only is that inefficient and ugly, think about what would happen if you had to scale that to the k largest items!

Answer (score 0):

As stated sorting is O(nlogn +5) iterating in O(5n + 5).  In the general case finding m largest numbers is O(nlog +m) using the sort algorithm and O(mn +m) in the iteration algoritm. The question of which algorithm is better depends on the values of m and n. For a value of five iterating is better for up to 2 to the 5th numbers I.e. a measly 32. However in terms of operations sorting is more intensive than iterating so it'll be quite a bit more until it is faster.

You can do better theoretically by using a sorted srray of the largest numbers so far and binary search to maintain the order that will give you O(nlogm) but that again depends on the values of n and m.

Comment: Added a follow up question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an array isn't the best structure for what you want. Specially since you need to sort it every time a new value is added. Maybe a linked list is better, with a sort on insert (which is O(N) on the worst case and O(1) in the best), then just discard the last five elements. Also, you have to consider that just switching a pointer is considerably faster than reallocating the entire array just get another element in there.

Why not an AVL Tree? Traverse time is O(log2N), but you have to consider the time of rebalancing the tree, and if the time spent coding that is worth it.

Comment: Added a follow up question.

Answer (score 0):

With usage of `min-heap` data structure and set heap size to `5`, you can traverse the array and insert into heap when the minimum element of heap is less than the element in the array.
`getMin` takes `O(1)` time and insertion takes `O(log(k))` time where `k` is the element size of heap (in our case it is `5`). So in the worst case we have complexity `O(n*log(k))` to find  max 5 elements. Another `O(n)` will take to get the excluded list.

Comment: Added a follow up question.